# Burn easter-eggs tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

First, [easter-eggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/easter-eggs) definition :

> These are “features” of an application or a program that usually have
>   little to do with the app/program's purpose. They are hidden (i.e. not
>   mentioned in the documentation) and typically require some elaborate
>   method to activate them.
>
> An example: Excel 97 had a flight simulator as an easter egg. One way
>   to activate it is described in that page.

I'm not sure to get the point of this tag: is it meant to share the easter-eggs found on softs & sites?

If I'm right, I feel it's off-topic for StackOverflow (as non programming related), **and propose to put it down.** But maybe I missed the actual purpose of this tag.

My interrogation comes from [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340604/why-does-pinterest-choose-this-particular-z-index-for-their-pinit-button) :

[image]

Thanks to [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) for pointing that out.

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Wow, that question is basically "Hey, remember the 80s?"

Comment: Which, coincidentally with my [angry old-man grumbling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340604/why-does-pinterest-choose-this-particular-z-index-for-their-pinit-button?noredirect=1#comment35741956_23340604) there, is a decade I'm trying my hardest to forget. After which it's the nineties...

Comment: Alternatively a less drastic course of action would be to simply make [tag:easter-eggs] a synonym of [tag:undocumented-behavior]

Comment: So, what about questions on implementing easter eggs? And if the tag is burned, what about questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759612/having-trouble-adding-skifree-as-an-easter-egg), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855758/can-anyone-explain-me-the-source-code-of-python-import-this) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084120/eprogrammernotfound-exception-in-delphi)?

Comment: @eis Those questions would be just fine without the tag.

Comment: Haha, I knew when I wrote my comment on that thread I'd quickly see a thread on meta. Its a tricky one, @eis has a good point, but the tag is maybe a little loose. Perhaps it just requires an improved wiki entry (e.g. focus on programming specific easter egg questions) or the usual vigilance when it comes to tag monitoring/retagging. That said, there are only 33 questions...kill it?

Comment: @Chris if the purpose of burning the tag is that it's off topic, aren't those questions equally off topic? or if the questions are not off topic, is that a justification for the tag?

Comment: @eis I think that some of the questions with the tag are off-topic according to current standards, and some are questions that stand as they are with or without the tag. There aren't a great number of them, and I don't think there's a catch-all way to handle them, nor does there need to be.

Comment: Why burning easter-egg tag should lead to burning the ego? Is this the expected result?

Comment: @J.Bruni I'm not sure whether it's written egg or ego, and assumed the former! But hey, these are cool flames.

Comment: I'm very interested in what the 5 followers of the tag have to say.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340604/why-does-pinterest-choose-this-particular-z-index-for-their-pinit-button 404 :/.

Comment: @zamber, one of the privileges of reputation is the ability to see deleted questions after they've been deleted. All others receive a 404. [Here's a screencap for reference](http://imgur.com/AfKISjN).

Comment: 8675309 (see the hover text): https://xkcd.com/1047/

Answer (score 14):

We shouldn't burn the tag... We should mind the carbon footprint of SE and try to keep it as green as can be. After all it started as a cleaner hybrid between forums and wiki's.

---

Perhaps we should edit the tag wiki, to make its useful purpose clear.

IMHO it shouldn't be used to share eggs –as that would make it just a copy of eeggs.com–, but should tag great questions regarding implementation details of eggs in the likes of:

[I'm looking for ways to obfuscate the following c#/silverlight source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238879/383793)

[So what exactly does “from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007289/383793)

[konami code in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546356/konami-code-in-flex)

Questions that about either implementing your own egg, or about getting documentation, that by definition doesn't exist. (ooh.... The one reason to burn it would be to avoid the paradox that follows from documenting eggs. But that I need to do more googling on Russell, Hilbert and Gödel, before I can decide on that problem...)

Comment: So, it would reflect the usage of the concerned piece of code: would konami-code tag (for example) follow this purpose in your opinion?

Comment: I think, roughly, [tag:konami-code] is to [tag:easter-eggs] as [tag:brainfuck] is to [tag:esoteric-languages].  Fun in itself [doesn't make a question bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: This is not what tags are for. What you're suggesting is keeping and using the tag as a meta tag. It would have no meaning. This tag is going to die.

Answer (score 13):

<sub>It seems several others agree with [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252514/burn-easter-eggs-tag?cb=1#comment8459_252514) so I guess its worth adding this as an answer to provide an alternative solution.</sub>

---

Easter-eggs, [according to the wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29#Software), are a manifestation of undocumented behavior.

I therefore suggest the quick, simple alternative to burning [easter-eggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/easter-eggs), is simply to make it a tag synonym of [undocumented-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undocumented-behavior).

<strike>As a minor bonus, it looks like the [undocumented-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undocumented-behavior) tag wiki is currently empty, so its up for grabs if anyone is interested.</strike>

Comment: From my point of view, this is the most constructive answer… [+1]

Answer (score 0):

That [Pinterest pin-it button question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340604/why-does-pinterest-choose-this-particular-z-index-for-their-pinit-button) **should** have been migrated to WebApps SE. We even have a [pinterest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pinterest) tag. That is our user community, well, kinda.

Can the question be resurrected and sent on to WebApps SE?

---

It would be better to disallow [konami-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/konami-code) U [easter-eggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/easter-eggs) questions than just getting rid of [easter-eggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/easter-eggs). Union questions are gems like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601834/anonymous-konami-code-asteroids (no, we don't want that on WebApps SE) whereas egg-only tagged questions would impact much-loved favorites such as:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910270/are-there-any-easter-eggs-in-base-r-or-in-major-packages (migrate to Cross-Validated SE?)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933870/easter-eggs-in-emacs

*This egg is kind of interesting: [Eclipse Search Results are Missing When there are Exactly 404 Matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853639/eclipse-search-results-are-missing-when-there-are-exactly-404-matches)

Comment: I doubt it, because it's not a question.  It's "Hey, lookie here".  It's appropriate for chat, not for SE.

Comment: No that question **shouldn't** have been migrated to Web Apps.