# Tag rename request: [egg] -> [python-egg]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

Some sources of confusion:

- [A Node.js framework](https://github.com/eggjs/egg)
- [A vision research library](http://visionegg.org/)
- [A toy programming language designed as a JavaScript exercise](http://eloquentjavascript.net/11_language.html)

Someone unfamiliar with Python could even take it for some kind of "easter-egg" tag.

Also, there is already `python-wheel`. Yes, `wheel` is more common to appear in programming questions than `egg` (I suppose?). In fact it has its own tag too, but it seems more consistent to prefix `python-` in both.

Comment: [easter-eggs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252514/burn-easter-eggs-tag) already happened...

Comment: None of those seem like sources of actual confusion yet. I think `[jar]` and `[gem]` are the closest analogies to `[egg]`, and they don't seem to have caused much confusion either (someone can correct me if I'm wrong about that). I would just leave it for now, and let people create `[egg.js]` and `[vision-egg]` tags if they need them.

Comment: Agree with @Bill here. I went through the excerpts of the questions that weren't related to [python]. There were 2 questions related to [tag:emacs-egg] which I retagged, 1 [off topic question about the nodeJS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55574638/4099593) and 1 question about StackEgg.